How can I link my .a files to my .hpp files?
I am trying to link my lib files with my header files, but every time it fails. I have changed tasks.json numerous times, but I cannot get it to work. The header part works, I know that, but I get
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvMbCZC.o:analysis.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

every time I try to run or build my code. I am new to c++ and want to use the curl library, but have tried
"command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-I", "C:\\Users\\PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Decenturm\\include",
                "-L", "C:\\Users\\PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Decenturm\\lib",
                "-o", "${workspaceFolder}\\analysis.exe", 
                "${workspaceFolder}\\analysis.cpp",
                "-lcurl" 

and alike many times.
I would be very grateful for any help
I expect the code to run - for the .hpp to find the .a files, and the reference to work.

Can you please [edit] your question to show us the full and complete build-log, including the actual command used to build?

What do you mean by linking header files?  Are you talking about dependencies in a make script or you talking about supplying header files to a linker?  Something else?
